# Blue screen when I shut down my PC after have used SDK android on Visual studio Community

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

So yeah, I'm building an app on Visual studio Community, and I started to get a blue screen with the error "Memory Managment". I figured out that is the Android SDK that cause this issue. I have 8GO of RAM I don't understand why this blue screen pop up

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add why you believe the Android SDK has caused this issue and more information about the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure that is the Android SDK that cause the blue screen because it appear only when I used the SDK before. After the blue screen of the death my laptop reboot and then nothing seems wrong. Maybe I should just uninstall/reinstall i don't know. Anyhow thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried reinstall visual studio a all his tool but nothing change.